# Moodle 2.5.1+ File Picker not working

Tags: moodle

I know that in Moodle 2.5.1+ there are some problems with the File Picker.
If editing is turned on, the File Picker doesn't work.  I was curious if anyone had found a solution for this as it would be much easier to create new SCORM packages or whatever without having to worry about turn editing on, add activity, turn editing off, upload file, turn editing back on. That seems really painful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it's _"not working"_?

Comment: @Nit If editing is turned on, the filepicker just displays the pinwheel.  Even if I go into the HTML to display the area containing the actual picker, the javaScript never loads so the picker doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: turn editing on, drag & drop SCORM zip file onto course page, select 'create SCORM', click 'OK'?

As for your 'file picker not working' issue:

- Have you turned on debugging ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging )
  ?
- Are there any errors displayed on the page?
- Are there any
  javascript errors in your browser (usually hidden away under some
  form of 'developer tools' in modern browsers, you haven't mentioned
  which web browser you are using, so I cannot give further advice
  here) ?
- Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of Moodle 2.5
  (2.5.6 was released on 12th May and has fixed a number of issues in
  2.5.1 - see http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Releases for details of all changes made) ?

Comment: There is nothing in the Moodle debugging; however, there is a javaScript error: "TypeError: node is null"  Also, I have access to all five of the most popular browsers (IE, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera) and all of their dev tools.

Comment: So which file is the error in, what line of code? The line just states that something wasn't set up correctly (probably an element on the page that was expected to be there, but isn't there).

Comment: I updated to the latest version of Moodle 2.5 and everything seems to be working fine now.  Thanks for your help.